# problems SocketException was unhandled

Tags: c#, socketexception

I was doing work in csharp, where I made a form with registration of users in the database, so when I opened this form button was used to refer to actually see the data of the users in the database, but it an acknowledgment of the `SocketException`, I know that a network error and my code is right so I do not know what to do to solve this problem can someone help me?

```
namespace exercicio_sharp_banco
{
    class banco_clientes
    {
        MySqlConnection conexao;
        MySqlCommand comando;
        MySqlDataAdapter captura;
        DataTable tabClientes;

        public void conectaBanco()
        {
            conexao = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;database=t3it1_dbdados");
            conexao.Open();//here and the warning
        }

        public DataTable mostraRegistros()
        {
            captura = new MySqlDataAdapter(comando);
            tabClientes = new DataTable();

            captura.Fill(tabClientes);
            return(tabClientes);
        }

        public void fechaBanco()
        {
            conexao.Close();
        }

        public void Consulta()
        {
            comando = new MySqlCommand("select * from clientes",conexao);
        }

        public void ConsultaPoa()
        {
            comando = new MySqlCommand("select * from clientes where cidade='Porto Alegre'",conexao);
        }

        public void ConsultaDinamica(string textoConsulta)
        {
            comando = new MySqlCommand("select * from clientes where cidade like '%" +textoConsulta +"%' ",conexao);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your sure your MySQL instance is running and configured correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This can have several reasons:

- Your firewall is blocking your MySQL-Server
- Your MySQL-Server is not running
- Your MySQL-Server is not configured properly